# How to correctly use ResidentArrays?

Tags: c#, hybridizer

When I create a FloatResidentArray for example, normally I would fill the array with data and then call RefreshDevice() to pass that information to the card.

However, what is the best way to handle the opposite situation where the ResidentArray is there to collect the results from a GPU calculation?

Obviously I’d have to create the array as normal, but do I have to pass the empty array to the device before the calculation or do I simply call RefreshHost() after the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resident array has two allocations, one on the CPU and one on the GPU, and a `Status` flag with three possible values: `NoAction`, `DeviceNeedsRefresh` and `HostNeedsRefresh`, see more on [documentation](http://docs.altimesh.com/api/Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports.ResidentArrayStatus.html).
When using the `[]` operator on the resident array, from the host, this flags gets updated. (you may also update this flag by hand).

If you use [HybRunner](http://docs.altimesh.com/api/Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports.HybRunner.html) to run the kernel, or the default Marshaler, it will update the `Status` flag and perform necessary refresh of data on the device. Otherwise, especially if using Streams, you may need to update this flag by hand.

Once calls are done, the data is retrieved either with `RefreshHost()` method, or simply accessing data with the `[]` operator (which will internally call `RefreshHost()`).

Advanced users may want to use [`HostPointer`](http://docs.altimesh.com/api/Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports.IntResidentArray.html#Hybridizer_Runtime_CUDAImports_IntResidentArray_HostPointer) and [`DevicePointer`](http://docs.altimesh.com/api/Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports.IntResidentArray.html#Hybridizer_Runtime_CUDAImports_IntResidentArray_DevicePointer) fields to have a fine grain control on the data.

Here is a short code snippet to illustrate the usage:

```
using Hybridizer.Runtime.CUDAImports;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HybridizerSample
{
    class Program
    {
        [EntryPoint]
        public static void Run(int N, IntResidentArray a, IntResidentArray b, IntResidentArray c)
        {
            Parallel.For(0, N, i => { c[i] = a[i] + b[i]; });
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 1024*1024;

            IntResidentArray a = new IntResidentArray(count);
            IntResidentArray b = new IntResidentArray(count);
            IntResidentArray c = new IntResidentArray(count);

            for (int k = 0; k < count; ++k)
            {
                a[k] = k + 1;
                b[k] = 10 * (k + 1);
            }

            Console.Out.WriteLine("c status is {0}", c.Status);

            cudaDeviceProp prop;
            cuda.GetDeviceProperties(out prop, 0);
            //if .SetDistrib is not used, the default is .SetDistrib(prop.multiProcessorCount * 16, 128)
            HybRunner runner = HybRunner.Cuda();

            // create a wrapper object to call GPU methods instead of C#
            dynamic wrapped = runner.Wrap(new Program());

            for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
            {
                wrapped.Run(count, a, b, c);
            }

            Console.Out.WriteLine("c status is {0}", c.Status);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("C = {0} , {1} , {2} , ...", c[0], c[1], c[2]);

            Console.Out.WriteLine("DONE");
        }
    }
}
```

And the expected output:

```
c status is NoAction
c status is HostNeedsRefresh
C = 11 , 22 , 33 , ...
DONE
```